# No access to suggested edits review on skeptics.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, privileges

The review page for the suggested edits at

```
http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits
```

only gives me a "Page not found" error when I try to access it. I do have more than 2k reputation and therefore the privilege "access to moderator tools". I also don't see the counter for pending edits that I should see at the top of the page.

Is that page disabled on beta sites or am I missing something else and I am not supposed to see it?

Comment: It looks like this value isn't part of the tiered beta privilege levels.  I've noted this internally.

Comment: @Rebecca I would be really useful, we have quite some pending edits that are overlooked.

Comment: This has been changed now, see http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/143/is-there-a-way-for-non-moderators-to-list-pending-edits/145#145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this was changed and is now linked to the mod tools privilege (which is already reduced during beta). – Rebecca Chernoff♦ "